# Is it faster to read raw json files or jsonified C# classes?

Tags: asp.net, json, performance, razor, getjson

It is easier for me to create the data my site uses in a .cshtml file that instantiates N objects of a class (as opposed to creating a .json file). I only recently changed to this method, after previously creating raw json files.

The code to read the data, whether .json or .cshtml, is the same:

```
$.getJSON('Content/noba.json', function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, dataPoint) {
    . . .

$.getJSON('getHugos.cshtml', function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, dataPoint) {
    . . .
```

Presumably, reading raw json, like such:

```
. . .
{
    "category":"Outdoor Literature",
    "title":"Almost Somewhere: Twenty-Eight Days on the John Muir Trail",
    "author":"Suzanne Roberts",
    "kindle":"B008SAOT4C",
    "hardbound":"--",
    "paperback":"0803240120",
    "imghref":"http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/B008SAOT4C/garrphotgall-20\" target=\"_blank\" ><img height=\"180\" width=\"120\" src=\"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/B008SAOT4C.01.MZZZZZZZ.jpg\" alt=\"Suzanne Roberts Book Cover\" /></a>"
  },
. . .
```

...would be more performant than this sort of thing:

```
@{
    var books = new List<BookClass>
    {
        new BookClass{Year=2013, YearDisplay="blankYearDisplay", Category="2013", Title="blankTitle", Author="blankAuthor", KindleASIN="blankKindleASIN", HardboundASIN="blankHardboundASIN", PaperbackASIN="blankPaperbackASIN", ImgSrc="blankImgSrc"},
. . .
        new BookClass{Year=2001, YearDisplay="2001", Category="Best Novella", Title="The Ultimate Earth", Author="Jack Williamson", KindleASIN="B00DV8TSHO", HardboundASIN="--", PaperbackASIN="1612421547", ImgSrc="http://images.amazon.com/images/P/B00DV8TSHO.01.MZZZZZZZ"}
    };
    Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Json.Write(books, Response.Output);
}
```

...which has to go through the additional step via ASP.NET of being converted to this:

```
[...,{"Year":2013,"YearDisplay":"2013","Category":"Best Novel","Title":"Redshirts","Author":"John Scalzi","KindleASIN":"B0079XPUOW","HardboundASIN":"0765316994","PaperbackASIN":"0765334798","ImgSrc":"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/B0079XPUOW.01.MZZZZZZZ"},...]
```

...but as we all know, presuming things sometimes gets us into trouble.

I know what you're thinking - just test it and find out; but I haven't created enough of the cshtml records yet to be able to compare the two approaches, but wonder if anybody knows whether the speed of loading raw json files would be noticeably speedier than converting the C# classes into json data? If so, I might have to revert to my previous methodology...

### UPDATE

You can check for yourself (www.awardwinnersonly.com), but based on my observations, two lists of about the same size (Books > National Outdoors Book Awards and Books > Hugos (Science Fiction), the first accessing a raw json file and the other the C#/Razor class converted to json, load at the same speed (I didn't use a stopwatch or such, but I'm looking more for just a general feel for which is faster). My next category (Spur awards), I will load an htm file, rather than doing any backend assembly line stuff, and see about that.

If anything, the cshtml file is faster than the NOBA json file; it is even faster than the Music > CMA json file, which has far fewer items. I don't know why that would be, unless the Razor engine is hyperoptimized for such operations or so.

### UPDATE 2

I didn't think of it until now, but this is an advantage of using C# classes that are jsonified over directly accessing a json file - I can (presumably, I haven't tried it yet) put a breakpoint in that C# code are step through it when it is called by $.getJSON('getHugos.cshtml')

Comment: As long as you've got one of each to go on, copy/pasting or looping the data to make it large enough to give you a valid test shouldn't be that hard.  Do it and tell us what's fastest!

Comment: I'll just wait until the first cshtml file is completed, and see if it seems snappier or molassesier than the others. I should have it done within a week or so; I was just wondering if somebody out there already knew for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a raw JSON file would work and save some computation required for serialization from C# into JSON. Moreover, there is extra overhead saved from having IIS not run the .NET pipeline but rather its more efficient "read-file and write to response stream" native code because it won't be dynamic. But the issue is that you are now stuck creating that raw JSON file either by hand or via a job. If you plan on maintaining it by hand, make sure that it's doable and won't change too often.

If it does, and you want to keep this more performant method of storing data needed on the client, you are going to have to maintain a separate piece of code that will refresh that file with appropriate values so you won't be saving lines of C# in the end anyways (though it won't be a difficult periodic task to write and is more performant).

Comment: All of these files (the 12 existing .json files, and the eventual 11 .cshtml files) will need to be updated once a year - when the new awards are presented. So about once a month I will add to a json file, and once a month I will add to a cshtml file. I have written utilities to do this, so it's basically a matter of data entry, and then copying and pasting.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that even though the two methods appear to load at the same speed in the browser, I am quite sure that the C#->JSON method will take more CPU per page load than straight JSON read-from-file. It may not matter now for your site, but being more efficient is always a good thing to strive for.

Comment: Yes, you're right. For my next award on (Spur), I'm going to go with straight html - instead of dynamically generating json files or class instantiation code as I gather data, I'll dynamically generate the needed html, and stash that in an .html file that I will call with jQuery like so: $('#BooksContent').Load('Spurs.html');